# Illustrator: Can't record certain things for the action I'm creating

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I've applied the transform effect to a layer so I can have radial symmetry for anything which is drawn inside it. now I also need to create an action which applies an Expand appearance on the layer and copies the content of the layer into the clipboard. everything is working when I'm doing it manually. however, when I try to record it for my action, the Expand Appearance future doesn't want to get recorded no matter what I do.

Am I doing something wrong or can't "Expand Appearance" be recorded for actions?

I tried things like recording it when expanding a group or even single objects instead of expanding a layer, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed that I've to use a different workflow to record some of the features in Illustrator (written below) which I've found reading the comments on this article https://forums.adobe.com/thread/977443

[image]

1. hit the little hamburger button on the top right corner of the Actions panel.
2. choose "Insert Menu Item..." from the appearing context menu.
3. in the text field of the appearing dialog window, write the name of the menu item you want to record (or click on it from the menu as the dialog window is open).
4. click "OK".
5. Check for yourself. it should be added to the selected action.

Comment: This is so close to helping me, but I need to set customized options on the inserted menu item so my outcome looks how I want it.